# Darth Vader to Lord Sidious

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader, darth-sidious

Darth tells Luke in Episode 6 (ROTJ)...

> "You don't know the power of the dark side, I **MUST** obey my master"

But ***why***? Why must Darth Vader obey his master?

Comment: Good question... Especially considering Vader explicitly goes against his master's wishes by killing him. Vader is just full of crap.

Comment: It's always possible that he **lied**.  He's a bad guy, after all.  They aren't known for their unfailing honesty.

Answer (score 11):

1. Effective power.

   Sidious is extremely powerful. If you recall, in Episode 3, he **beat Yoda** in straight-up fight. He murdered his previous Sith Master Plagueis.

   Previously, he cut off Vader's hand as punishment for failure.
2. Irreplaceable knowledge.

   - Vader requires deep knowledge of Dark Side to survive, and to fulfill his dream of getting better from his injuries (being able to breathe without a suit).
   - Sidious is the only one who knows the secrets of life and death and immortality, same lure he used to sway Anakin to Dark Side in the first place.

Comment: Sidious was the most powerful Sith Lord of all time. Anakin didn't truly comprehend this in *Revenge of the Sith*, but he most certainly did by the time *Return of the Jedi* rolls around. Vader tells Luke, *"you don't know the power of the dark side"* because he believes Luke is being naive, just like he was.